# Is Angular faster than pure JavaScript when considering DOM manipulation?

Tags: javascript, angular, performance

This is what I know so far:

- when modifying DOM, Javascript vanilla does that directly and every time so it is computationally expensive
- I know that React and Vue.js use virtual DOM so they do not update the real DOM if it is unnecessary but what about Angular. How does Angular do that?

In a real world app does it really matter which one is faster?

Comment: Angular has its own change detection that has a similar philosophy to the virtual DOM but functions differently. It avoids making updates or more specifically checking for changes where it's not necessary based on the DOM hierarchy. As for DOM modification with vanilla JavaScript, there's nothing stopping you from doing your own change detection or maintaining your own virtual DOM either on your own or through a framework like https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom ... So it's specious to say that React/VUE are faster than vanilla JS, and virtual dom can be slower in some cases.

Comment: In a real world app, you should pick a framework based on if it makes you more productive or not.  When your choice of framework begins to exhibit performance issues, *then* you can begin to identify where to optimize for performance.  Choosing to not use a framework because it *might not be as fast as something else* is a fools errand, unless you know from the ground up that the app demands the highest performance possible in every single interaction.  And in that case, you probably aren't doing anything client side anyway.

Comment: "*Javascript vanilla does that directly and every time*" - of course not, you wouldn't write dumb code. Whatever framework you use, it'll have some overhead, which may be small but cannot be negative.

Comment: Is it better to load a library file to manipulate DOM or is it better to use pure JavaScript to manipulate DOM?

Comment: great thoughts so far. I agree with you all :)

Comment: Vanilla Javascript will at least be slightly faster. The problem is you would have to write your own change detection. And you lose all the other bonus stuff from Angular(or any other framework for that matter). The question you have to ask yourself, do you really want to reinvent the wheel for maybe a 5% better performance? The great thing about frameworks is, they help you achieve faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does Angular do that?

As already mentioned, Angular has its own change detection strategy. Long story short, it patches some specific objects (like browser events, xmlHttpRequest, timeout and so on) to know when to start checking and checks values that [matter](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/)

So this kinda mix with events and dirty checking. If you want some comparison - try to check this [article](https://itnext.io/angular-5-vs-react-vs-vue-6b976a3f9172)

> In a real world app does it really matter which one is faster?

In a real world all depends on requirements and situation. You should start from the question -what do I want to achive? If you want flexibility - take React. If you want more stable structure and guidelines - take Angular. If you want compromise - take Vue. If you need to save client traffic - try Hyperapp or smth like that.

And to be honest, Angular, React and Vue are fast enough for most of applications so you shouldn't worry about that from start.

Comment: And to top it off, Angular team is still working harder to make the applications more faster and faster,

Comment: @Arun Angular ivy will be released later this year, promising a huge reduction in build size and probably faster rendering too.

Comment: yeap, I also heard that Angular is getting a lot better and faster with every release

Comment: @MatthiasL Does that mean it has been pretty bad in the past? :-P